# Type inference for MultiToken in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, dependency-injection, type-inference, angular-dart

Using `Dart 2.5.0`, `Angular 5.3`.

Given the following component:

```
const MultiToken<String> stringsToken = MultiToken("stringListToken");

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<div>{{ myStringValues.join(", ") }}</div>',
  providers: [
    ValueProvider.forToken(stringsToken, "one"),
    ValueProvider.forToken(stringsToken, "two"),
  ]
)
class AppComponent {

  final List<String> myStringValues;

  AppComponent(@Self() @Inject(stringsToken) this.myStringValues);
}
```

I'm getting the exception

```
dart_sdk.js:101871 EXCEPTION: Type 'List<dynamic>' should be 'List<String>' to implement 
expected type 'List<String>'
```

This happens when the constructor tries to inject the provided `List` value to the local `myStringValues`, as if the provisioned `List` was downcasted to `List<dynamic>`. Now, if I replace the token creation with

```
const MultiToken<String> stringsToken = MultiToken<String>("stringListToken");
```

the component will work as expected, the injected values will be displayed.

How come that, using the first declaration syntax, the type of the `MultiToken` could not be inferred to `String`? To add to my confusion, if using the first version of declaration, i.e.

```
const MultiToken<String> stringsToken = MultiToken("stringListToken");
```

and then printing the `runtimeType` of `stringsToken`, it will print `MultiToken<String>`.

So where, and how, the bound generic type, is lost in the first case, when trying to inject the value?

Comment: Did you try to specify the type on your provider ? `ValueProvider<String>.forToken`

Comment: @HadrienLejard yes that didn't work either

Comment: It may be a bug in the angular compiler, you should report it (https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/new)